# Strip HTML in excel and populate different cells

Tags: html, excel, vba

Can someone help me strip down HTML code and populate different columns in excel?

For eg.
If my HTML code is:

```
<p></p>10-16-2013 22:35<br/>I love pizza! Ordering was a breeze!<p></p>10-16-2013 13:19:46<br />this has time stamps too!<p></p>10-21-2013 11:55<br />This is a test<br />
```

How can I output it as separate columns in Excel like this?

```
 Column A               Column B
 10-16-2013 22:35       I love pizza! Ordering was a breeze!
 10-16-2013 13:19:46    this has time stamps too!
 10-21-2013 11:55       This is a test
```

Will be extremely grateful if someone can help me out!

Comment: look at the InStr() and Replace() methods. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Try the two functions I mentioned and come back with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different options you might try for parsing the html:

1. Combine InStr, Mid and/or Replace as mehow suggests.
2. Use VBScript's RegExp library.  You would need to include it into your VBA project by clicking "Tools" ---> "References" and then checking the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5".  Regular Expressions are a very powerful text parsing tool, but it does take some time to get used to the syntax.  I found that this pattern allowed me to get the dates/comments as submatches: `<p></p>([^<]*)<br />([^<]*)`.  I assume you are pulling that example out of a full webpage, so you would need to tweak that pattern to match exactly the parts of it that you are looking for.  [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) has a good tutorial on using the VBScript RegExp library.
3. Use a higher level HTML parser. I suggest the MSHTML library, which you can add to your VBA project by clicking "Tools" ---> "References" and then checking the box next to "Microsoft HTML object library".  This parser is aware of constructs like HTML paragraphs, breaks and tables.

In my opinion, if you're willing to take the time to learn it, Regular Expressions would be your best bet.  The InStr/Replace method may not be able to account for the variability in the webpage content and the HTML method would probably be overkill, especially given the lack of formatting in the example HTML.

Once you've parsed it, you can tackle the second part of the question using Excel Worksheet and Range objects.  Like wehow noted, if you can put together some code it will be easier to help you.